# batch file to call an exe application

Tags: batch-file, splunk

I have a script which I can run perfectly if I call it manually in the command prompt.

```
cd \
cd impressio
cd input

for %%f in (.txt)do (
 echo "%%~nf"

"C:\Program Files\Splunk\bin\splunk cmd python" "D:impressio\deployment code\add_null.py" "%%~nf.txt" "%%~nf_processed.txt"

)
```

When I save this script as `<filename>.bat` and double-click, it always prompts me an error message: *"Program Files is not recognized as an internal or external command"*.

Is it because of the environment variable setting issue? Did anyone come across such thing before, or does my code have a problem?

Comment: It smells like a long-filenames issue.

Comment: Also, you can type `cd \impressio\input` instead of three individual `cd` commands.

Comment: hi Eitan,
Thanks for the suggestion. 
i also felt weird when i type manually in cmd it work!! :(

Comment: Where is this `<filename>.bat` script located?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure why `Program Files` is mentioned in the error message, but there does seem to be an issue with the line where you are calling your Python script.

In particular, this bit:

```
"C:\Program Files\Splunk\bin\splunk cmd python"
```

should likely be this instead:

```
"C:\Program Files\Splunk\bin\splunk" cmd python
```